# Why does $f(x_n)\rightarrow 0$ imply that a subsequence converges to zero of $f$?

Tags: limits, algebraic-number-theory, irreducible-polynomials, local-field, nonarchimedian-analysis

Let $f$ be a separable and irreducible polynomial of degree $d\geq 1$ with coefficients in a local field of characteristic $p$, say $K= \mathbb F_p((T))$ and $f\in K[X]$. Assume there is a sequence $(y_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ in the separable closure $K^s$ satisfying 
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(y_n) = 0.
$$
I want to show that there is a subsequence $(y_{n_{k}})_{k\in \mathbb N}$ converging to a zero $x$ of $f$ in $K^s$.
I don't know much about non-archimedian analysis and I wonder if the proof can be stated similar to the real case?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one can prove it in the following way:
Let $x_1, \ldots, x_d$ be the different roots of $f$ in $K^s$. Then $f$ can be written in the form 
$$
f(T)= (T-x_1)\cdots (T-x_d).
$$
Assume there is no subsequence $(y_{n_k})_k$ that converges to any zero $x_i$ for $i=1,\ldots ,d$. So we can choose $\varepsilon \gt 0$ and $N\in \mathbb N$ such that for all $n \geq N $ and all $i=1, \ldots , d$ we have
$$
\mid y_n - x_i \mid \gt \varepsilon.
$$
Therefore $\mid f(y_n) \mid \gt \varepsilon^d \gt 0$ for all $n\geq N$ and we have a contradiction.